# Hadamard finite part in 2 dimensions

Tags: integration, regularization

given the divergent integral

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}dx \int_{0}^{\infty}dy \frac{xy+x^{3}-y^{2}}{1+xy+x+y} $$

how could i get a finite value in the sense of Hadamard finite part integral ??

thanks,

for the one dimensional case i know how to do it , but how is it done for multivariable calculus?? should i first perform integration over $ dx$ and then over $ dy $